# IIS ARR with wordpress not working from internet Error timeout

Tags: wordpress, iis, timeout, arr

I have an IIS server in my network with a domain configured who based on some ARR rules on the web.config shows a wordpress that is installed with xaamp in other server in my network.

So when yo go to example.com it shows the wordpress that its in 192.168.110.104:8080

When I try to access to example.com from my network, seems like the rules works fine and the wordpress content it works properly but when I try to access to the domain example.com from the internet it shows a lot of errors as looks like it's trying to load 'internal resources' form internet? obviously it load without css styles, some images works, some not, so it's a mess.

Errors are timeout like this.

```
GET http://192.168.100.104:8080/wp-content/themes/astra/assets/css/minified/style.min.css?ver=2.4.4 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

In the wordpress I have configured the :

wordPress (URL) as http://192.168.100.104:8080
web url : http://192.168.100.104:8080

Maybe I have to place the domain there instead the local ip?

This is my web.config from the IIS

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="homepage.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
            <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
          <add origin="*">
            <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
          </add>
        </cors>

        <rewrite>
        <rules>
  
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://192.168.100.104:8080/{R:1}" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
        <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://192.168.100.104:8080/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://example.com/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
        </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="NoControl" />
        </staticContent>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, origin, content-type, accept" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>    
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: hi there, any ideas?

Comment: It is difficult to determine where the problem is based on the current information. I suggest you try to use FRT to view the details of the error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis